# Rebuild project for lower sdk/jdk. Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Tags: java, android, linux, sdk, intellij-idea

I have an android project which was build under `jdk 1.7`. I have all `4+` and `2.1 -2.3 sdk` packages in my `InteilJ` enviroment. All the time the project was tested under `jdk 1.7`, and `v4.0++ emulator`. Now I want to run it on device with `2.3.5` android api version but it responds with `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]` . I downloaded older `jdk 1.6` and set `2.3` api for project. Even it passes rebuilding, the project can't start on real device. I've set `minSdkVersion` in manifest. When I start new project with above settings it works on this `2.3.5` device. Any ideas, sollution ?

Comment: "I've set minSdkVersion in manifest" -- set it to what? "I downloaded older jdk 1.6 and set 2.3 api for project" -- none of that is relevant to your issue. Your issue is that Android thinks that your `android:minSdkVersion` is set to a value higher than your device runs. A normal 2.3.5 device is API Level 10, so Android thinks that your APK is set up for `android:minSdkVersion` of 11 or higher.

Comment: v11... so trivial. I have not checked it so. Write it as an answer and I will mark it as a sollution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the installation failure error messages are not easy to understand in all cases.

`[INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]` means that the minimum API level of the APK you are trying to install (`android:minSdkVersion`) is higher than the API level of the device you are trying to install it on.

In your case, a normal Android 2.3.5 device will report that it runs API Level 10. I say "normal", because a vendor firmware or ROM mod could report that it runs API Level 3, or API Level 1337, though usually the API level is not tinkered with this way.

In your case, it would appear that the manifest of the project has an `android:minSdkVersion` of 11 or higher. There is nothing wrong with that... except that the app will refuse to install on Android 1.x/2.x devices and emulators.